# EF Wont generate connection table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I´m trying to connect two tables but i don´t understand why it not creates the connection table. I would be really thankful if any one could take a peek.

Thanks in advance! :)

Edit: Included the datacontext. The table User and Project are created successfully but don´t get the dbo.ProjectUser...

User model:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string SurName { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string Domain { get; set; }

    public DateTime? TimeInDomain { get; set; }

    public DateTime? TimeInCompany { get; set; }

    public Project Project { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User> manager)
    {

        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Project model:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Platform { get; set; }

    public DateTime ProjectStart { get; set; }

    public DateTime ProjectLaunch { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Datacontext:

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public DbSet<Project> Projects {get; set; }

    public DataContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static DataContext Create()
    {
        return new DataContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create M:N relationship between Project and User? If so, create another class name it like User2Project.

Comment: If EF doesn't succeed you should get some exception when trying to generate a database from your classes. But you don't show enough details. Is there any mapping involved? Do you have multiple context classes?

Comment: Edit some text and inculded the datacontext

Comment: And why both `public Project Project { get; set; }` and `public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }`?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, deleting one fixed it. Tank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User` has two properties referring to `Project`:

```
public Project Project { get; set; }
public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
```

By default (without a `User` property in `Project`), EF will consider the first property as one end of a one-to-many relationship. Normally, it will also assume that the other end is `Project.Users`. Apparently (I didn't know that), the presence of `User.Projects` makes EF decide that all associations are independent of one another: `User` has two FKs to `Project`, `Project` one FK to `User`. I think EF should have thrown a model builder exception telling that the other end of `Project.Users` is ambiguous.

So you have to tell EF how you intend the associations to coexist:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Projects)
    .WithMany(p => p.Users)
    .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("UserId").MapRightKey("ProjectId"));
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(u => u.Project) // Or HasRequired
    .WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("ProjectId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```